# Coverting csv into numpy array

Tags: python, csv, numpy

So I have downloaded the MNIST digit dataset from a Kaggle competition and I want to edit the 'train.csv' file so that I can train my neural network.
The 'train.csv' file has 42000 rows and 785 columns. Each row represents an image. The first column contains the label i.e the number in the image and the rest of the columns are the pixel values of the 28X28 image of the digit.

I want to be able to store the first column as a 'training_result' vector and the rest as 'training_inputs' matrix.

So first I load the csv file using pandas.

```
data = read_csv("train.csv")
```

Now to create the training_result vector, i tried this:

```
 training_result = data[0:42001][0:1]
 >>training_result.shape
 (1,785)
```

So i am getting one row x 785 columns instead of 42000 rows x one column. Is there a mistake in the slicing operation?

Also for getting training_inputs, I tried

```
training_inputs = data[0:42001][1:785]
>>training_inputs.shape
(784,785)
```

I get 784 rows x 785 columns instead of 42000 rows x 784 columns.

How can I rectify this mistake?

Comment: Your slice (`[0:1]`) means to return a list containing just the first element of the list you sliced. It just so happens that you sliced the list twice: first (`data[0:42001]`) returned all the elements, then the second was applied to the result of the first. The `[]` operator in python is not a matrix notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood the error i was doing. Basically, I was trying to do multi array slicing but the syntax used was wrong.

So if I want my training_inputs variable to have 42000 rows and 784 columns from the dataset 'data', I should do the below

```
training_result = data[0:42001,1:785]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
training_result=data[0].values
training_inputs=data[1:].values
```

Comment: Jesse, thanks for your response!  In order to make StackOverflow a valuable resource for programming information, could you please add some explanation for why your solution would fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check the shape of data to see if it is correct. If it is good, then I think you should interchange the way your are indexing.

`training_result = data[0:1][0:42001]`

and

`training_inputs = data[0:784][0:42001]`